# What are the pros and cons of Vienna's publicly owned social housing market?

Tags: social-welfare

[This article](https://www.huduser.gov/portal/pdredge/pdr_edge_featd_article_011314.html) and [this article](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/vienna-affordable-housing-paradise_n_5b4e0b12e4b0b15aba88c7b0) report on Vienna's social housing market. Rent controlled since 1917 and now publicly owned.

What are the relative pros and cons from an economic standpoint of such a policy? How's it working there?

Why is it apparently unique in the world? What are the barriers to copying its successes elsewhere? What, if any, are its failures?

Comment: One could ask, from an economics perspective, why should rents in Vienna be half (per sq.m) what they are in Budapest... (approx 5.5 vs 11 euros). The dubious answer I received on politics SE [on a similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50540/is-the-cap-on-rental-prices-in-berlin-lower-than-the-average-price-in-some-easte) is that a city should only compare with itself...

Comment: On the "not a plus" side, it doesn't seem to shield you from a housing bubble in the remaining private sector. https://www.reuters.com/article/austria-economy-cenbank/austrias-hot-housing-market-warrants-scrutiny-central-bank-says-idUSL8N28C1LM